# Spark - How to do rollup on a defined heirarchy where parent element not present in dataset

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to create a spark application to do aggregation on hierarchical dataset.

Example scenario is as follows.

I have a dataset contains the following rows
[image]

I have a hierarchy of categories defined in my database. My Hierarchy is as follows

[image]

I need the aggregated result for each of this element in the category hierarchy.

Similar to this I need the counts for all element in the hierarchy nodes.

**Expected output:**

[image]

Comment: Can you share the structure of the table you want as a result? Or if it is not a table, example code for input and output you would want? (Are positiveCount, categoryId and date parameters to a function?)

Comment: Unclear example in all honesty.

Comment: @Gofrette -  I have updated the dataset based on your suggestions. Please have a look

Comment: @thebluephantom Updated the question. Please have a look

Comment: I am assuming the hierarchy is a separate dataset and the example is all on 1 line.

Comment: @thebluephantom yes. hierarchy is in a separate dataset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming the "parent element" which is not present is 4002 given its in your hierarchy, not in your input, but in your output.  If not, you really need to be more specific.

In any case, you should read the "hierarchy" data set into a second data frame and join it to your first data frame.  But you have to make sure its prepared properly.

A good approach would be to denormalize the hierarchy a bit.  Turn it into this:

Category | Parent Category

So, category 4020 would have 3 rows:

```
Category | Parent Category
4020     | 4015
4020     | 4002
4020     | 4000
```

Then after joining your data to this, you can do a simple aggregation/sum, by the parent category and date for each value column.

Comment: I have added one more entry for 4020 | 4020 as well.